# Bitmapdata blendmode and alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there anyway to apply both alpha and BlendMode.HardLight when drawing using bitmapdata?

```
var processImageBmd:BitmapData=new BitmapData(900,900);
processImageBmd.draw(backgroundImage);  //backgroundImage is a sprite                               

processImageBmd.draw(frontImage,null,null,BlendMode.HARDLIGHT);//frontImage is a sprite
```

Basically I need to apply alpha (let's say alpha = 0.4) and BlendMode.HardLight to frontImage. I successfully apply the blendmode hardlight to front image, but can't figure out how to make it alpha.

Comment: I believe you can set alpha on the colorTransform parameter.  I'll see if I can make an example

Comment: I found the solution same as you :) just came back and saw your answer. So I gave ya the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `colorTransfrom` passed to the draw function.

So for your scenario, this should do the trick:

```
var ct:ColorTransform = frontImage.transform.colorTransform; //copy the current colorTransform so you don't have to mess with colors
ct.alphaMultiplier = .4; //set it's alpha to .4;
processImageBmd.draw(frontImage,null,ct,BlendMode.HARDLIGHT); //pass your color transform to the draw command
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You have to pass a `ColorTransform`, which contains a alphaMultiplier parameter.

```
BitmapData.draw(IDrawable, Matrix, ColorTransform, BlendMode, ClipRect, smoothing)
```